# Copy File Assets To SDCard Activity (Android app) need ideas

Tags: java, android

I need to copy all folders inside Assets to specific folder on SDCARD. Lets say our target folder called "RESULT_HERE" under folder called "MAIN_FOLDER"

I used this code but no result at all. Can't copy files or even create the folders.
[I used this code](https://github.com/PareshMayani/Android-CopyFiles/blame/master/CopyFileAssetsToSDCard/src/com/paresh/copyfileassetstoAssets/CopyFileAssetsToSDCardActivity.java).

Any ideas?

Comment: How does it fail?  That code seems to have at least some log messages in it, so what do you observe in your device log when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

I modify a code to copy all folders and files with the same structure of Assets folder. Just replace the code of **CopyFiles** method.

```
private void CopyFiles(String sdCardPath, String assetFilename){
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    try {
        String[] files = assetManager.list(assetFilename);

        //Try as file
        if(files.length == 0){
            InputStream in;
            OutputStream out;

            String fileName = assetFilename.substring(assetFilename.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);

            File file = new File(sdCardPath + File.separator + assetFilename.substring(0, assetFilename.length() - fileName.length()));
            if(!file.exists())
                file.mkdir();

            in = assetManager.open(assetFilename);
            out = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName);

            copyFile(in, out);

            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        //Try as folder
        else{
            for (String assetFile : files){
                String newAssetFilename = assetFilename.length() > 0
                                                    ? assetFilename + File.separator  +assetFile // Is on internal folder
                                                    : assetFile;                                // Is on root of asset folder

                CopyFiles(sdCardPath, newAssetFilename);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To call this function you must invoke :

```
if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        CopyFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + INTERNAL_PATH, "");
```

where **INTERNAL_PATH** is the relative path of your folder. The function **Environment.getExternalStorageState()** is to ensure that SD Card is present.

Also, remember then you must declare a follow permission on Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```